# X11 on MacOS won't start with ssh -X user@host (failure to open gedit)

Tags: linux, ssh, gedit

I use a Macbook at home to ssh/sftp into the (Ubuntu) Linux server at work, and have gedit installed on both.

I installed X11 (XQuartz) on my Mac with the intent of using gedit and other applications when on ssh remote connection.

The problem is that the login

```
ssh -X user@host
```

fails to activate X11, i.e. giving the error

```
Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated
```

When on the server, typing gedit or gedit  fails to open the remote file (no error message, but no X window opens nor does anything else happen). What's frustrating about this is that this had previously worked, so I'm not sure what can be done to trouble-shoot the issue. As far as I'm aware, I haven't made any changes to my permissions or other settings on either the remote Ubuntu Linux server or my local MacOS laptop.

N.B. Using ssh -Y instead of -X gives essentially the same error

Comment: I googled `Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated` and found loads of similar questions with answers and suggestions on serverfault, stackexchange, unix.SE and Apple Discussions.

Comment: That's right, and almost all of them tell you to use ssh -Y rather than ssh -X, or tell you to update/reinstall X11. I just installed the newest version of Xquartz a couple of weeks ago, and I get the same errors with ssh - Y as -X.